# Move Image With Scroll & Transform in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm trying to move image with js when using mouse scroll, but its not working ,Im using wordpress plugin (Header and Footer Scripts) for add js code.

```
<script>    
$(function(){
    var scroll = document.querySelector('#jstest');
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    var value = window.scrollY;
    scroll.style.transform = 'translateY(${value})';
    })
    });
</script>
```